# QGIS distance matrix in meter instead of decimal degrees

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance-matrix

I created a point layers of store locations and customers in Florida by given coordinates (WGS 84 EPSG: 4326). Now I need a distance matrix between stores and customers, but the result is in decimal degrees, I think.

I understand I have to reproject the 2 layers so that I can work with meters but how does this work in QGIS i.e. which projection should I use, and which setting should I use?

Answer (score 6):

You have to reproject your coordinates to a cartesian system, like UTM. To do this, first, look at the UTM zone for your region, for example [in this site](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) and take note of the EPSG or Proj4 definition. Then, in QGIS, save the vector layer with another name, using "save as". You will be given the opportunity to specify a new SRS. Lastly, open the new layer and compute the new distance matrix. It will give you the results in meters.